# JSLint mode for JSHint

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

After years of happily using jslint, I need to start using jshint, partially for its ES6 support.

Is there a .jshintrc that will give me the same strict settings I had in jslint?  Or is there some "jslint: true" setting someplace that I'm missing?  I realize I can go through all the options one by one and try to create this, but it just seems like the kind of thing that would be out there somewhere.